# how to call function in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the below mentioned function in jQuery i need to call it but dont know how to do it. 
Please share any feedback its quite ure

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    var url="example4.php";
    $('#letter-a').click(function(){
        $.getJSON(
            url + '?callback=?',
            function(data){        
                $('#content').empty();
                $.each(data, function(index, entry){
                var html = '<div class="entry">';
                html += '<h3 class="word">' + entry['word'] + '</h3>';
                html += '<h3 class="word">' + entry[ word ] + '</h3>' ;
                html += '<div class="function">' + entry['function'] + '</div>';
                html += '<div class="definition">' + entry['definition'] + '</div>';
                html += '</div>';
                $('#content').fadeIn().append(html);
            });
        });
    return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Your code has many syntax errors.

Comment: You could solve this by just googleing

Answer (score 2):

Call it by clicking on the element with ID `letter-a` or programatically:

```
$("#letter-a").click();
```